# Clarifai API and cURL?

Tags: http, curl, access-token

I'm following Clarifai's guide to make a cURL request and get the tags related to the image.

In the guide it says that I can do either this:

```
curl "https://api.clarifai.com/v1/tag/?url=https://samples.clarifai.com/metro-north.jpg" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer {access_token}"
```

or this:

```
curl "https://api.clarifai.com/v1/tag/" \
  -X POST --data-urlencode "url=https://samples.clarifai.com/metro-north.jpg" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer {access_token}"
```

So what I do is that I type in the access token that I get when I create a new application and I change the link of "samples.clarifai.com" for a random link of a random image, but every time I want to do this I get the following message on terminal:

```
{"status_code": "TOKEN_INVALID", "status_msg": "Token is not valid. Please use valid tokens for a application in your account."}
```

Any idea why I keep getting this eben though my access token is right?

Thanks!

Comment: well, to be brutally honest, it looks like your token is not valid; maybe you're using the `{}` that you should be removing, or the other way around?

Answer (score 1):

Just so there can have an official answer for this but [Marcus Müller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4433386/marcus-m%C3%BCller) is totally right.

You should be sure to **remove** the braces with the Bearer access token. But you still want to be sure everything else is fine. This does assume though that you have generated a proper access token either by the [Developer Documentation](https://developer.clarifai.com/guide/#authentication) or within your [Applications page](https://developer.clarifai.com/account/applications/) once you have logged in.